# Response.Write Base64 string

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I receive a Base64 string which is actually the string representation of a PDF file. I want to  write this string with Response.Write, but without converting it back to its binary representation.

I tried this:

```
var base64string = "...";
Response.Write(base64String);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
```

The browser does not recognize the content as a base64 encoded PDF file. How can I fix this?

EDIT: this is the response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 11 Apr 2012 11:00:04 GMT
Content-Length: 107304

JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKMSA... more content here
```

Comment: Have you tried `Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard, fileContet is not byte, is a base64 string

Comment: I think you need to add the headers / type *before* using `Response.Write`?

Comment: @pjumble, it doesn't matter the order (since I don't end the response). And I checked with fiddler, it writes the headers ok)

Comment: _without converting it back to its binary representation_ - You want to leave that to the Browser? Why?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I believe is some kind of yo-yo stuff, like converting an int to string and then back the string to int. I want to pass the file as I receive it from a third party webservice.

Comment: I don't think browser will convert such thing on its own..

Comment: @ShadowWizard You can use a base64 string with CSS to set a background-image, Mozilla has built-in JavaScript functions to encode, decode, etc. But while I'm searching into this and found nothing, I believe is a standard only for SMTP

Comment: @ProgrammingHero, ok, thanks, I found this on other several locations. You can post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Content-Transfer-Encoding` is not a valid HTTP header; this is an old header from MIME. It's HTTP equivalent is `Transfer-Encoding` which supports the following values:

- chunked
- identity
- gzip
- compress
- deflate

If you have a Base64 encoded PDF document, there isn't a "from base64" transform in HTTP which will decode this document for you, so you **must** decode it on your server, prior to putting it in the response body.

If you want a stream that converts from Base64, you can use a [`FromBase64Transform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.frombase64transform.aspx) into a [`CryptoStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx):

```
new CryptoStream(fileStream, new FromBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
```

Comment: It makes sense. Since SMTP works only with ASCII, base64 was introduced to transmit the binary data in this form, but HTTP understands binary so there was no need to use base64.

Answer (score 3):

When you promise a  PDF with

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
```

You should also deliver one by opening the Response Stream and write the *binary* version of the PDF there.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. And also the binary data is much lighter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
var base64string = "...";
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
Response.Write(base64String);
Response.End();
```

May be this will help you